# How to deploy a dotnet core app using AWS CodePipeline to ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

I'm trying to build a basic dotnet core application and deploy it using the default tool available to me in AWS. I currently have the following steps working:

1. Repository in CodeCommit
2. Checkin triggers CodeBuild build step on the Ubuntu image "aws/codebuild/dot-net:core-2.1" which runs the yml file(which creates the correct files I need to actually run the web app):

   ```
   version: 0.2

   phases:

   build:
   commands:
     - dotnet restore CMS/CMS.csproj
     - dotnet build CMS/CMS.csproj
     - dotnet publish CMS/CMS.csproj -o site
    artifacts:
     files:
       - CMS/site/**/*
       - CMS/aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json
   ```

aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifestVersion": 1,
    "deployments": {
        "aspNetCoreWeb": [{
                "name": "CMS",
                "parameters": {
                    "appBundle": "./site",
                    "iisPath": "/",
                    "iisWebSite": "Default Web Site"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

3. CodeDeploy takes the artifacts and published them to an elastic beanstalk application configured to use windows. It's currently running the default application.

It runs through each step fine and I get green check marks throughout, but when I navigate to the EB instance the original site is still shown, showing me that my application hasn't been deployed. Is there something I'm missing?

I was really hoping I would be able to deploy an app from check in to finish without needing to modify a build environment, at least right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a buildspec.yml I wrote to create the beanstalk package from CodeBuild.

```
version: 0.2

phases:

  build:
    commands:
      - dotnet restore EbCiTest/EbCiTest.csproj
      - dotnet build EbCiTest/EbCiTest.csproj
      - dotnet publish EbCiTest/EbCiTest.csproj -o ./staging/app
      - cp ./EbCiTest/aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json ./EbCiTest/staging/.
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  base-directory: 'EbCiTest/staging'
```

I think the trouble you are having is the zip file being created contains the full paths to the files so aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json is not at the root of the zip file. I suggest copying everything to a staging folder and then using that staging folder as the base-directory which will be the root of the zip file.

Comment: This did it. Thank you so much! I was getting very frustrated because it seemed like a few different tutorials had you doing manual work or using the AWS tools on visual studio and I just couldn't get anything to deploy using code pipleline.